# How to append text to a 'column' value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to run a number of cleanup on a DataFrame.
In order to keep track of what happened to the data, I added a column called `applied_rules` to the DataFrame.

At each step, I want to add a line to the `applied_rules` column if the record has been updated.

Typically, it looks like:

```
mask = df['type'] == "test"
df.loc[mask, 'value'] = "updated"
df.loc[mask].assign(applied_rules=lambda x: x.applied_rules + "Rule 1 - ...")
```

All, the `applied_rules` return empty.

If I use:

```
mask = df['type'] == "test"
df.loc[mask, 'value'] = "updated"
df[mask]['applied_rules'] += "GR001a - updated position because it was not corresponding to a standard one\n"
```

Only the last value gets stored.

What is the correct way to append text to a value?

Comment: df.loc[mask, 'applied_rules'] = df.loc[mask, 'applied_rules'] + 'your text here'

Comment: Have you tried using `apply()` method of `pandas.DataFrame`. Worth to try: (1) Try using a copy of data frame and apply on that copy. (2) Use pandas.DataFrame convention and try `pd.Series() + str`. For example, df.loc[mask, 'applied_rules'] = df[mask]['applied_rules] + your_string_here

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with `mask`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
         'type':['text',"test",'text',"test","test",'text'],
         'applied_rules':list('aaabbb')
})

mask = df['type'] == "test"
df.loc[mask, 'value'] = "updated"
df.loc[mask, 'applied_rules'] += " GR001a... "

#alternative
#df.loc[mask, 'applied_rules'] = df.loc[mask, 'applied_rules'] + " GR001a... "

print (df)
   type applied_rules    value
0  text             a      NaN
1  test  a GR001a...   updated
2  text             a      NaN
3  test  b GR001a...   updated
4  test  b GR001a...   updated
5  text             b      NaN
```